# why Durbin Watson result could be so different from Ljung-box or Breusch–Godfrey test for OLS diagnostics

Tags: r, regression, autocorrelation, diagnostic, durbin-watson-test

I have a residuals series from OLS regression (out.lm) where I do **NOT** have lagged dependent variable as a predictor. My residual series has about 1700 numbers. I ran `DW` test in R, which gave results as follows:

```py
dwtest(out.lm)
    Durbin-waston test
    data: out.lm
    DW = 2.1554, p-value = 0.9992
```

I know DW test only counts autocorrelation at lag 1, so I used Ljung-box with lag 1 to verify it, but it gave me a quite different result.

```
Box.test(out.lm$residuals,1,type="Ljung-Box")
X-squared = 10.61, df =1 ,p-value = 0.001125
```

Same contradiction observed for Breusch-Godfrey test:

```py
bgtest(out.lm)
LM test = 13.448, df =1, p-value = 0.0002452
```

I also tried different lags for Ljung-Box and BG test, it gave similar result as lag 1.

Why different conclusion? Even if it is possible to have a different conclusion from different tests, why is the difference surprisingly large? Did I do anything wrong or misunderstand anything here? I also attached acf/pacf plot for the residuals. The serial correlation actually looks not very bad for me. May I know what should be the right conclusion here or what else I can do to make a better conclusion?

acf and pacf for my residual:
[image: img]

Comment: Use dwtest(out.lm ,alternative ="two.sided") to have the alternative hypothesis: **autocorrelation is not 0**
instead of **autocorrelation is greater than 0**.